# How to store JSON efficiently?

Tags: json, database, configuration

I'm working on a project which needs to store its configuration in a JSON database.

The problem is how to store efficiently that database, I mean:

- don't rewrite the whole JSON tree in a file for each modification
- manage multiple access in read/write at the same time
- all of this without using an external server to the project (which is itself a server)

Comment: Use a database that is specialized to the purpose, like mongodb or couch.

Comment: Well, one way or another you need to "flatten" the JSON into conceptual pieces that go together and can rationally updated separately.  You must do this with some knowledge of the "meaning" of the data, not just it's physical structure.

Comment: How about, storing it in a normal database similar to wordpress.. like say the table: | 'key' | 'value' | , and then converting the table rows to json?

Comment: Hot Links: The main application (the daemon) has no idea of the configuration stored by the modules (this is why I choose JSON). So, it is impossible to "flatten" the JSON into multiple pieces.

goldenparrot: Using a relational database to store non-relational data, isn't it overkill ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an idea which fits to my needs :

- For the in-memory configuration, I use a JSON tree (with the [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) library)
- When I need to save the configuration, I retrieve the XPath of each elements in the JSON-tree, to use it as a key and store the key/value pair in a BerkeleyDB database

For example :

```
{'test': {
  'option': true,
  'options': [ 1, 2 ]
}}
```

Will give the following key/value pairs :

```
      Key        | Value
-----------------+-----------
/test/option     | true
/test/options[1] | 1
/test/options[2] | 2
```

Answer (score 2):

take a peek to MongoDB, wich uses Bson (binary json) to store data. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Inserting

Edit 2021:

**Today I better recommend to use postgresql to store json** :
https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/using-postgresql-for-json-storage

Comment: It implies to have a MongoDB server which is running in order to have access to the configuration. And how to store configuration to access to the database ? (host/port).